# Problem using Axios FormData in React-Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I have read so many different documentations now but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in my Axios request.

I'm working with a Recat-Native frontend and a Django backend. It al started with that I tried to set up a Axios Formdata transfer for images. But I couldn't get it to work, so I rolled it back to a simple API with only 3 lines of data. But I can't get it to bite.

Testing the API using Postman everything works fine. So it should not be related to the back-end but something in my react-native/axios code.

```
putThis =async ()=>{

        const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append('free_wo_num',this.state.wo_num);
        formData.append('free_med_slug',this.state.med_slug);
        formData.append('free_to_share',this.state.to_share);
        await axios({
            url: '/auth/womedia/'+this.state.med_slug+'/',
            method: 'PUT',
            data:formData,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
            .then(response => { console.log('put');})
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
    }
```

My Django code

```
class MediaWOAPIview(APIView):
    serializer_class=MediaSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def put(self, request, **kwargs):
        obj = Free_Media.objects.get(free_med_slug=self.kwargs.get('str'))
        serializer = MediaSerializer(obj, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Free_Media
        fields=('free_wo_num','free_med_slug','free_to_share')
```

This is how the API data looks when doing a GET request, when I log it in the react-native console.

```
Object {
  "free_med_slug": "jonas2-1-2",
  "free_to_share": false,
  "free_wo_num": "jonas2-1",
}
```

This is how my formData looks like if I try to update one of the values.

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "free_wo_num",
      "jonas2-1",
    ],
    Array [
      "free_med_slug",
      "jonas2-1-2",
    ],
    Array [
      "free_to_share",
      true,
    ],
  ],
}
```

What is it that I have missunderstod?

Answer (score 0):

I now found an answer, this is apparently related to a well known issue with Axios.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406#issuecomment-1048693170

By installing Axios v0.24.0 it worked.